# What is the default filesystem of Amazon Linux AMI 18.03

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I am logged into EMR master node, which is an EC2 instance launched using `Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03 release`. and executed below commands and their outputs are as follows:

```
uname -a
Linux ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx y.yy.yyy-yyy.yyy.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP <TimeStamp Data> x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/os-release

NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

I've 3 queries as follows about the above EC2 instance:

```
what is the operating system?
what is default filesystem?    
what is root volume?
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating system, in this case, is `Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03`. You can also find the details about the operating system by typing the command **lsb_release -a**. The sample output of this command will be something of this format.

```
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:       Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:           18.04
Codename:          bionic
```

For the next 2 questions, you can try this command. `df -Th`. This gives you the detail about all the filesystem present in this instance. The sample output of this will be something like this

[image: Filesystem]

In the above output, you can see Filesystem `/dev/xvda1` of type `ext4` is mounted on `/` which acts as root volume.

You can also try this command if this instance has the required permission. `aws ec2 describe-volumes` to get the detailed information about all the volumes. You can filter for a specific instance as well. Check this for more detail [Describe volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html)

You can also check these details in the AWS EC2 console. Go to the EC2 console, type your instance IP. In the Description tab, you will find many useful details. For example, you can get detail about root device like this.

[image: Root device details]

You can click on that link and it will take you to the Volume console, which will have all the information associated with root volume.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ajay, this partly answers my queries, however, I've 2 doubts and followed exactly as u suggested and here is the outcome: for OS details, I did lsb_release -a which returned:
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: AmazonAMI
Description:    Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
Release:        2018.03
Codename:       n/a

Comment: I can not see in the above lsb_release output which linux distribution or operating system this Amazon AMI is using under the hood?

Comment: 2nd doubt: I followed through the root device /dev/sda1 to the volume console, and got its size: 100GB, but I am not able to connect this with above command df -Th results, there we say filesystem /dev/xvda1 of type et4 is mounted on / i.e. root so how this is connected/related with the /dev/sda1 root device

Comment: Hi @Manoranjan. Related to the first doubt: As you have noticed the output of the command `lsb_release -a`. The value for the description would be generally the name of the operating system. In this case, it is `Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03`. Amazon has its own Linux distribution that is compatible with both Red Hat Enterprise Linux and CentOS. In your command `PRETTY_NAME` would be the name of the operating system. To understand this better, you can run both of the commands on some other Linux machine and you can relate the output even better. In short, `Amazon Linux AMI` is the OS name.

Comment: To the second doubt, These are just the naming convention. If you look at the Device naming documentation, you will find this: `Depending on the block device driver of the kernel, the device could be attached with a different name than you specified. For example, if you specify a device name of /dev/sdh, your device could be renamed /dev/xvdh or /dev/hdh. In most cases, the trailing letter remains the same.` In your case, The device `/dev/sda1` is attached to the instance as `/dev/xvda1`.  Check this for detail https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html

Comment: 1 last doubt, In this question's description:  cat /etc/os-release prints ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora", so does it mean the operating system is "RHEL FEDORA"? and Amazon Linux AMI built on top of it or uses it under the hood

Comment: Your understanding is correct. `ID_LIKE` represents `identifiers of operating systems that are closely related to the local operating system in regards to packaging and programming interfaces`. Example: for an operating system with "ID=centos", an assignment of "ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"" would be appropriate. For an operating system with "ID=ubuntu", an assignment of "ID_LIKE=debian" is appropriate. Please check `man os-release` for the detailed explanation around this.

In your case `Amazon Linux AMI` is the operating system itself which resembles most closely to `rhel fedora` architecture.